# "Internet connection is offline" when connecting to AP without internet access - WiFi off/on fixes

Tags: ios, wifi, router

**BACKGROUND**
We're trying to use an iOS app running on iPhone/iPad to give WiFi credentials to an embedded device (using an ARM SoC running Linux). The embedded device starts an AP (access point), we instruct the user to connect to this AP and then the user submits their WiFi credentials. After WiFi credentials are received the device drops the AP and connects to the WiFi the user gave credentials for. 
Initially, we try to hit a PHP page to get the list of WiFi networks the embedded device can see.

**ISSUE**
We instruct the user to join XYZ network (in iOS they must background the app, go into settings and switch to our WiFi network). We listen for an app resumed from background notification, check the devices current ESSID (ensure its our AP ESSID) and try to hit a PHP page to receive the list of WiFi networks. Often, this connection fails reports "The internet connection appears to be offline" (or something of that nature).

We currently have a stop gap when this happens telling the user to toggle their WiFi off and then back on (in settings). The device will reconnect to our AP as it's the most recently connected network. This ALWAYS fixes the issue, we've never had to toggle the WiFi twice in order to reach the PHP page on the device. Please tell me any possible way we can avoid having to instruct the user to toggle WiFi and still access PHP pages on the embedded device.

Note: when we're connected to the AP (whether this bug is active or fixed) the device DOES NOT show the WiFi icon in the status bar. We assume this is because the AP doesn't have a viable connection to the internet (can only access pages served by the embedded device). We've been testing on a device that has LTE cellular access, but the error still says "Internet connection appears to be offline".

Obviously we have a DHCP server running on the embedded device.

Comment: WiFi icon shows exact WiFi connection not Internet. If you don't see WiFi icon that device is not connected to WiFi network. Also I'm not fully understand what exact you want to achieve. Could you describe it more?

Comment: @Skie We can get response from PHP scripts when this bug doesn't show and there's no WiFi icon. So we must be connected or we wouldn't get PHP response.

Comment: Could an error with the DHCP server cause the phone to not show the WiFi icon yet still send/receive through the connection? We're serving out 10.10.10.100->10.10.10.199 IPs.

Comment: It is strange enough. May be connection established for very small time or like that. On my 6 year experience I never see that connection work without connection icon (WiFi/Cellular/Bluetooth)

Comment: My suggestion try to record video and post it here with whole process.

Comment: Our setup process lasts about 10 minutes (after the point where this bug can appear passes) and it NEVER shows the WiFi icon. This must have something to do with the bug I've described. Anyone know what checks Apple uses to determine whether or not to show the icon?

Comment: Sure, I'll record a video but I won't be able to until later this evening. Thanks Skie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's looking like this was caused by an omission in our dhcpd.conf file.
This omission was causing iOS to believe the connection was unviable.

We added the following line and are getting much better results:

```
option domain-name-servers 10.10.10.1;
```